# Modifying top of priority queue of custom objects

Tags: c++, priority-queue

Suppose that I have a custom struct

```
struct custom
{
  int quantity;
  double price;
}
```

and a priority queue of custom objects:

```
std::priority_queue<custom, std::vector<custom>, some_custom_comparer_t> pq{...}
```

The `some_custom_comparer_t` will only sort `custom` based on price only and not quantity. Is there any way to make it so I can change the `quantity` of the `custom` object at the top of the `priority queue`?

I understand that I won't be able to change the price because the STL container does not allow for adjusting the keys of of the priority queue, but in this case, I want the code to recognize that the `quantity` variable is not a key and allow me to modify it.

So far, my solution is to pop it off, adjust the quantity, and push it back in.

Comment: Are you familiar with `mutable`?

Comment: @DrewDormann I think so. It just allows a member function declared as constant to modify the variable declared as mutable? Or is there something else that it does in this case?

Comment: [Good discussion of what Drew's hinting at here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)

Answer (score 2):

Make the quantity `mutable`.  A *mutable* member of a class may be modified, even in the context of a `const` class instance.

```
struct custom
{
  mutable int quantity;
  double price;
};
```

> So far, my solution is to pop it off, adjust the quantity, and push it back in.

Now you can just do:

```
sq.top().quantity = new_quantity;
```

Comment: Ohh. I didn't actually think they would work. I thought I had to do some modification of the internal priority_queue structure itself. What if I wanted to modify the price instead? How would this idea tell the STL container that it may potentially need to heapify the modified item?

Comment: @user5965026 if the `priority_queue` is ordered by `price`, you change `price` at your own risk. The `priority_queue` will not know you did it and not rearrange the contents of the queue. In that case you must remove, change, and reinsert  in order for the new `price` to be respected. Mind you, changing the ordering key is probably Undefined Behaviour, so the program could do something utterly bizarre like sign you up for the Book of the Month Club.

Comment: also, `const_cast`